# Android activity does not finish and does not launch previous activity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 Activities the main activity I have called Map activity and the second that I have called Question activity when the app launch the Map activity is shown then you click the play button and the Question activity is launched with **StartActivityForResult()**, then when you have answered the question right the Question activity should be destroyed and created again and check the number of right answered questions and change the layout. then if you have scored 5 then Question activity should be destroyed and the Map activity will be shown but this is not happen. Here is my code

**Map.class**

```
public void OnClick_Question(View v){

    Intent i = new Intent(MapActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);        
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(SharedPrefs.TAG, "OnActivityResult Entry");
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Log.d(SharedPrefs.TAG, "MAPActivity OnActivityResult Entry resultCode");           

        AssignContentView(requestCode);
    }
}
```

**Question.class**

```
public void Next() {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();

}

public void LevelUp() {
    Log.e(SharedPrefs.TAG, "LevelUp");        

    super.finish();
    finish(); /*This don't happen*/
}
```

When I see LogCat shows me this message:

```
09-01 11:23:03.911     901-1485/? W/ActivityManager﹕ startActivity called from finishing ActivityRecord{43386100 u0 com.example.gbb/.QuestionActivity t50 f}; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=com.example.gbb/.QuestionActivity }
```

Why I am doing this, is because I want to change the layout of Map Activity depending in your score.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think this code is not enough to answer your question. When are the LevelUp() and the Next() methods called?

Comment: Thanks Nabin, Next() is called when you have answered the question in other words load a new question, And LevelUp() launches when you score 5 right answered questions.

Comment: Why are you using both super.finish() and finish()?

Comment: to try to finish the Question activity but nothings happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by adding `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in the Android Manifest. Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thanks @a-unknown-hacker, I have tried and now instead of reload the question activity until reach the score, the map activity is shown.

Comment: IF the answers work for you, please select this answer as 'selected' (By clicking on the tick mark).

Comment: Thanks, but any of these answers help me to solve the problem, I'm still finding an answer or a workaround. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by turning off Instant Run and re-running my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

We need to keep the request code to be in global and static variable to access in `onActivityResult` method

```
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 111;


    public void OnClick_Question(View v){

        Intent i = new Intent(MapActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);        
        startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.d(SharedPrefs.TAG, "OnActivityResult Entry");
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:

            Log.d(SharedPrefs.TAG, "MAPActivity OnActivityResult Entry resultCode");           

            AssignContentView(requestCode);
             break;
              default:
                break;
}
        }
    }
```

I think there is no problem in your `Map` class, the problem is in second class.i.e., you need to set the `RESULT_OK` in that intent and then you can check `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)` in `onActivityResult` method. Below you can find the code for that

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 setResult(activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
 finish();
```

Hope this is helpful:)